# Executing sql in procedure with concatenated command string

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, db2, execute

I have this here:

```
create procedure test_ins(IN tab varchar(128))
Language sql
begin
   DECLARE stmt_ins STATEMENT;
   DECLARE v_query varchar(2048);
   DECLARE test varchar(20);
   DECLARE test_tab varchar(20);
   set test = 'HERE IT IS';
   set test_tab = tab;
   set v_query= 'INSERT INTO '||test_tab||'(test, free) values (test,'''')';
   PREPARE stmt_ins from v_query;
   EXECUTE stmt_ins;

end@
```

The problem is that it seems to run (no error message) but there is nothing in the table....

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: can you try: set v_query= 'INSERT INTO '||test_tab||'(test, free) values ('||test||','''')';

Comment: Or, if my comment above  does not work: set v_query= 'INSERT INTO '||test_tab||'(test, free) values (''test'','''')';

Comment: both don't work

Comment: well, at least we have fixed a potential future problem. Can you also try "EXEC SQL EXECUTE stmt_ins" at the end.?

Comment: Also please try: EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt_ins;

Comment: Oh found it, we are forgetting single quotes, should be like 'Here it is', which is '''||test||''' . Updated my answer, check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change test to '||test||' in set v_query like below:

```
create procedure test_ins(IN tab varchar(128))
Language sql
begin
   DECLARE stmt_ins STATEMENT;
   DECLARE v_query varchar(2048);
   DECLARE test varchar(20);
   DECLARE test_tab varchar(20);
   set test = 'HERE IT IS';
   set test_tab = tab;
   set v_query= 'INSERT INTO '||test_tab||'(test, free) values ( '''||test||''','''')';
   PREPARE stmt_ins from v_query;
   EXECUTE stmt_ins; 

end@
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not using a debugger...try the one in IBM Data Studio (free [download](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/)).

```
create or replace procedure test_ins(IN tab varchar(128))
Language sql
specific test_ins
begin
    DECLARE v_query varchar(2048);
    DECLARE test varchar(20);
    DECLARE test_tab varchar(20);
    DECLARE stmt_ins STATEMENT;
    set test = 'HERE IT IS';
    set test_tab = tab;
    set v_query= 'INSERT INTO '||test_tab||'(test, free) values (''test'','''')';
    call dbms_output.put_line(v_query);
    PREPARE stmt_ins from v_query;
    EXECUTE stmt_ins;

end@
```

Comment: Debugger doesn't start (user-id does not have priviledges) (I'm admin on the machine), however it doesn't work. nothing in the log table and no errors

Comment: Debugger works fine for me, as local-admin, so you've got a different issue not related to your question. The exact code I show in my answer works correctly. Your code may differ. If the exact code above yields neither and insert nor an error, then you are omitting some information.

Comment: When I just execute the statement directly it works with prepare and execute it doesn't

Comment: Does the *exact code* shown in my answer work on your environment?  It does not help you if you change the question inside a comment!

Comment: No it doesn't sadly

Comment: Then you are omitting vital information.  As you appear to be a learner with sprocs, you either need a debugger, or liberal use of dbms_output.put_line to *show* what's actually running.

Comment: sad thing, the dbms_output is not showing in command line or data studio, it works directly so I have to work with that I guess

Comment: For command-line (db2cmd) operation, the dbms_output requres you have run at the command line `db2 set serveroutput on`, before invoking the sproc.

Comment: Finally got it ... it is '''||test||''', ''''